# Php cronjob doesn't run

Tags: cron

I have 3 Debian servers. For years I was using this command to run a php cronjob:

```
19,56 * * * * /usr/bin/php /home/sites/cron.php >/dev/null 2>&1
```

it works on my first server. On the second server it doesn't work and I use:

```
19,56 * * * * php -f /home/sites/cron.php >/dev/null 2>&1
```

on the third server don't work any commands. I tried:

```
19,56 * * * * /usr/bin/php /home/sites/cron.php >/dev/null 2>&1
19,56 * * * * /usr/bin/php -f /home/sites/cron.php >/dev/null 2>&1
19,56 * * * * /usr/bin/php -q -f /home/sites/cron.php >/dev/null 2>&1
19,56 * * * * php -f /home/sites/cron.php >/dev/null 2>&1
19,56 * * * * php -q -f /home/sites/cron.php >/dev/null 2>&1
19,56 * * * * php /home/sites/cron.php >/dev/null 2>&1

whereis php 
php: /usr/bin/php /usr/share/man/man1/php.1.gz


19,56 * * * * /usr/bin/wget -O - -q -t 1 http://www.example.com/cron.php
```

I am getting crazy. Never in my life had problems like this. Any ideas how to set up a cronjob? Thanks.

Comment: How exactly does it not work? Does the script never run? Or nothing gets to the output?

Comment: Maybe run it without the output redirects so you can see what it's doing?

Comment: I just discovered the following problem. The cronjob actually runs and the script is being excecuted but for some reason the script can't include another file: include_once 'conf.inc.php'; I tried: include_once '/full/path/conf.inc.php'; but it doesn't help. It's strange. never had such a problem.

Comment: Just copypaste the content of your conf file into your main php.

Answer (score 1):

Please post the relevant error messages. Reschedule the cron job like this:

```
19,56 * * * * /usr/bin/php /home/sites/cron.php > /home/<user>/cron.err 2>&1
```

Look what is present in the file /home//cron.err. Or simply run the command in a terminal

```
/usr/bin/php /home/sites/cron.php
```

and verify if it is working.

Comment: Barun, thank you for your reply. As I wrote in my previous comment, the problem is somewhere else - the script can't include another file with database iformation: include_once 'conf.inc.php'; I tried: include_once '/full/path/conf.inc.php'; but it doesn't help.